# React Native - dynamically change TouchableHighlight under image from mutliple TouchableHighlight using loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I have post list, and there is a favourite image on each posts. when I click on single favourite image, then that only clicked image should be changed dynamically, not all images.

I am facing issue that when click on single image, then all images are changed.

```
favoritePostClick (this){

  this.setState({
      favoriteSelected : !this.state.favoriteSelected,
  });
}

<TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.favoritePostClick.bind(this)} key={"touch_" + this.state.lstSuggestedFRABS[i].freebs_id}>
              {this.state.favoriteSelected ? <Image source={require("../../Images/Icons/favoriteOk.png")} /> :
                <Image source={require("../../Images/Icons/favorite.png")} /> }
            </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem."

Comment: Update the issue with some code please.

Comment: <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.favoritePostClick.bind(this)} key={"touch_" + this.state.lstSuggestedFRABS[i].freebs_id}>
                  {this.state.favoriteSelected ? <Image source={require("../../Images/Icons/favoriteOk.png")} /> :
                    <Image source={require("../../Images/Icons/favorite.png")} /> }
                </TouchableHighlight>

----------------

favoritePostClick (this){
     
      this.setState({
          favoriteSelected : !this.state.favoriteSelected,
      });
    }

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, do you have answer ?

Comment: @NileshPrajapati This is not valid syntax `favoritePostClick (this){` you can't name your parameter `this` it is [reserved keyword](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-keywords)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko can you please share your code on my issue?
thanks in advance

Comment: @NileshPrajapati I don't think I have any code on your issue. Really.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko see i have attached code in my question. now if you have any answer, then let me know.